# Is there a Russian cognate of Ukrainian кравець, Polish krawiec meaning tailor?

Tags: этимология

Also, I'm curious if there is a reconstructed Slavic root or if it's a loan (nothing found in Derksen).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure about exact proto-Slavic root but it's generally accepted as word of (at least) eastern-Slavic origin. And, as of Russian, yep, cognates for "[кравець](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C)" are "[кроить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)" and its derivatives, such as "[крой](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9)", "[закройщик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA)".

"Закройщик" is not exactly a tailor but it's a related profession by the way.

Comment: There's one more Russian word, _кравчий_ "the head of the monarch's waiters, the servants at the monarch's dining table", probably a borrowing from the Polish _krajczy_ with the same meaning, though. Still, the idea of cutting is present.

Comment: @YellowSky yep, and if we want to go further, закрома, укромный, скромый are also related ) I might be wrong but as far as I remember  Ukrainian "крок" is also related by the way.

Comment: Ukrainian "крок" (а step) doesn't fit here, it's a cognate of "окорок" (ham, hind quarter) and "каракатица" (cuttlefish), all three from Proto-Slavic _*korkъ_ (leg), cf. Bulgarian "крак" (leg). As for "закрома, укромный, скромный" I'm not sure, they have the root _-кром-_ (also in "кромка") with the meaning "edge; to bite (as in "кромсать")". _To bite_ and _to cut_ have semantic affinity, but the sound is rather different from "kraj-/krav", as for me.

Comment: @YellowSky oh, good to know about крок!